# sql datetime queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have tables with this type of datetime: `2010-09-16 00:32:41.960'` CreatedDate column.

I need to perform a query ... where [CreatedDate] >= '2010-09-16 00:32:41.960' 
but that just gives me

`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

What is the correct syntax, it's been a while since I've done SQL the last time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an unambiguous datetime format so SQL Server doesn't have to guess how to convert it:

```
where [CreatedDate] >= '2010-09-16T00:32:41.960'
```

It's a shame that, depending on your regional settings, it may interpret the form with a space separator (rather than `T`) as `YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss`. Which gives an out of range month with your example (and wrong results for dates early in the month, except when day=month)

I'd normally list the safe formats as:

- `YYYYMMDD`
- `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss`
- `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil`

There are some other formats that are now safe if converting to `datetime2` or `date`, but I can't remember them, and the above usually suffice.

---

Another alternative would be to run a [`set dateformat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) statement before using these date literals:

```
set dateformat mdy
select MONTH('2010-09-16 00:32:41.960')
```

Gives `9` as the result, whereas what you're experiencing can be reproduced with:

```
set dateformat dmy
select MONTH('2010-09-16 00:32:41.960')
```

Comment: I cannot make changes to the DB, I know it's an obsolete format but still need to use it :( but the query works, thanks

Comment: @sd_dracula - Have you seen my edit? Also, I'm not sure what changes you're talking about making - I thought this was just a query...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
where [CreatedDate] >= CONVERT(datetime,'2010-09-16 00:32:41.960');
```

Comment: `CAST` or `CONVERT` without a format specifier will perform exactly the same conversion as in the original query - and fail for the same reason.